# Send email when any cell in column is changed to 'YES'

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a Yes/No column (column AP) and I need to send an email notification whenever any value within that column is changed. I have worked out how to send one when a specific cell is changed:

```
function sendNotification(e) {


if("AP4" == e.range.getA1Notation()) {
if(e.value == "YES") {



 //Define Notification Details
 var recipients = "***********@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Update"+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "This cell has changed";

 //Send the Email
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}
}
}
```

However, I need this to work for any cell within column AP.

I also then need to store other values with the changed row as variables to use within the email body. So for example, the product name is in column B, and I need to be able to access this name so that my message reads something like "Column AP has been changed to 'Yes' for " + productName. Any help would be received very gratefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendNotification(e){
if(e.range.getColumn()==42 && e.value=='YES'){
 var recipients = "***********@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Update"+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "This cell has changed";
 var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it and get an error on line 2. Assume this is a) because of the 'and' and b) because of the single equals? I tried this line: if(e.range.getColumn()==42 && e.value=='YES'){ instead but that doesn't work either :(

Comment: I had a couple of errors there.  The && for "and" and the == for =.  The second one was an assignment rather than a comparison.

Comment: haha! Yes just tried the same changes but it doesn't appear to be working :(

Comment: Actually scrap that - that does seem to be working now :) Thank you! Do you have an answer for the second part? How to store a value from the row which has changed as a variable? I need to be able to use the value in column B of the changed row in my email that is generated so need to store it...

Comment: try this `var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();`

Comment: This is a great and works well. The only thing I am struggling with now is the fact that this column gets amended to yes/no automatically via another script. I assumed that the onEdit trigger would work on this but it doesn’t seem to recognise this as an edit event. I tried using the onChange trigger as well but no luck. So the function works if I manually change a cell in column AP to ‘yes’ but not if a cell in this column is changed to ‘yes’ via my other script...

Comment: That’s correct The onEdit trigger only responds to user actions

Comment: Hmmm any other way to approach this?

Comment: Try sending the email in the script that would change the value

Comment: How do I get the script to run on a particular sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking.  Perhaps `getSheetByName('mySheet')`

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to know how I to use this script to send email when there's a change in a column from "No" to "Yes" on a particular sheet.

I'm trying this, 

function onChange(e){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
 if (e.range.getColumn()==2 && e.value=='Yes'){
 var recipients = "xyz@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Update"+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "This cell has changed";
 var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 }
}

Comment: I also end up with this error - TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.