# Send email when multiple conditions across multiple columns are met - Google Sheet Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first time posting here and I'm a newbie when it comes to understanding code. I'll try my best to clarify what is the desired result and where I am at.

I have a "column A" which is a dropdown which contains Options "1,2,3,4,5". 
In the same sheet I have another column - "column B" which is a dropdown which contains options "A, B"

**Desired Outcome** - Whenever the user selects option "2" and option "B", an email should get triggered to a recipient.

**Current State** - I've browsed through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265577/send-email-when-any-cell-in-column-is-changed-to-yes/48267617#48267617?newreg=aeda9b75479e4ef2b1adb5fb0b58de65) and Cooper's solution got me to a certain extent. However, I'm not able to send the email when there are two conditions to be met. This is how I've set the trigger - The function sendNotification --> From spreadsheet --> On Edit

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT - This is the code I'm using -

```
    function sendNotification(e){
     if(e.range.getColumn()==9 && e.value=='Approved'){
      var recipients = "blah@blah.com";
      var subject = "Custom Subject Line";
      var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
      var body = "Custom body with variable - " + valColB + "from the sheet titled - " + e.range.getSheet().getName();
     MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 }
}
```

EDIT 2 - This was an alternate method I tried, but somehow even this did not work. It wouldn't work the moment I put in the IF statement inside funTwo.

```
function funOne(e) {
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 5 && e.value == 'Option 2') {
    funTwo();
  }
}

function funTwo(a) {
  if(a.range.getColumn() == 9 && a.value == 'Option B') {
    MailApp.sendEmail('blah@blah.com, 'subject', 'body')
 }
}
```

Comment: Edited the question to include the code snippet as well

Comment: "Approved" is one of the options in one of the columns in my actual sheet. It's equivalent to option "B" in the question

Comment: What have you tried to test this script out? I.e. logging of executions via `console.log(e)` and then altering the sheet in "expected" manners. Does the script work if you write Approved instead of select via drop-down? Which letter column is Approved in? Are you or users likely to have selected a multi-cell range (in which case `e.value` is `undefined`)?

Comment: @tehhowch As I mentioned earlier, I'm new to coding overall, so I'm not sure if I've done what you've mentioned. I have however tried to write the code in a different manner by calling function2 from function1. eg - I made a function funOne which had the 1st condition in an IF statement and if the condition is true i called the second function -funTwo. In funTwo I put a simple send mail command. This worked absolutely fine. The problem came when I put the second condition inside funTwo using an IF statement. It stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a another condition with `offset`:

Try changing from

```
if(e.range.getColumn()==9 && e.value=='Approved'){
```

To

```
if(e.range.getColumn()==9 && e.value=='Approved' && e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue() == '2' ){ //if ninth column is edited to Approved and the corresponding eighth column is 2, then...
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you @|'-'|  !! This worked flawlessly! I tried to upvote it but it wouldn't accept it as I'm a newbie here. But thank you so much! :)

Comment: Just out of cuiriosity, could you help me understand why my second method did not work? What was I doing wrong? I've edited my question to include the code for the second method that I was trying. Thanks!

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! I have accepted the answer. And thanks so much for sharing those links. Will go through them